# AngularJS : ng-repeat doesn't detect changes in scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been reading through various post, questions, answers and documentation but haven't managed to solve my problem so far.

I'm using mbExtruder jQuery plugin, and to integrate it within angular, I've created a directive for it:

```
directive('mbExtruder', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict : 'A',
                link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var mbExtruderConfigurationAttrs = scope.$eval(attrs.mbExtruder);
                    mbExtruderConfigurationAttrs.onExtContentLoad = function() {
                        var templateElement = angular.element(angular.element(element.children()[0]).children()[0]);
                        var clonedElement = $compile(templateElement)(scope);                       
                        scope.$apply();
                        var contentElement = angular.element(angular.element(angular.element(element.children()[0]).children()[0]).children()[0]);
                        contentElement.replaceWith(clonedElement.html());
                    };
                    element.buildMbExtruder(mbExtruderConfigurationAttrs);
                    $.fn.changeLabel = function(text) {
                        $(this).find(".flapLabel").html(text);
                        $(this).find(".flapLabel").mbFlipText();
                    };
```

I'm extracting the container div, compiling it, applying scope and replacing the original div with the transformed one.

Now, I'm using the ability of mbExtruder to load contents from separate HTML file which looks like this:

```
<div>
<ul>    
    <li ng-repeat="property in properties">
        <span><img ng-src="../app/img/{{property.attributes['leadimage']}}"/></span>
        <a ng-click="openDetails(property)">{{property.attributtes['summary']}}</a>
    </li>
    <div ng-hide="properties.length">No data</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

And, in the HTML of the view I have following:

```
<div id="extruderRight"
        mb-extruder="{position: 'right', width: 300, positionFixed: false, extruderOpacity: .8, textOrientation: 'tb'}"
        class="{title:'Lista', url:'partials/listGrid.html'}">
    </div>
```

The scope I'm getting in the directive is the scope of the parent controller which actually handles properties array.
The thing is that, if the properties list is pre-populated with some data, that ends up in the compiled HTML - cool. But, any change to properties does actually nothing. I've added watch handler on properties within directive and really, that is triggered whenever any change is made to properties, but, ng-repeat does not pick that up. The original idea is to have properties list empty in the beginning - that causes ng-repeat compile to have just this output:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: property in properties -->
```

Is this doing a problem? The fact that ng-repeat declaration has actually disappeared from DOM.

Am I missing something obvious here? I've read the documentation on $compile and ng-repeat and I would say that I don't need to manipulate DOM by myself, ng-repeat should do its work. Or I'm totally wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kHxGd2SUGP03iWs0Lcnt?p=preview)

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: If the `ng-repeat` comment appears without any contents, that means `properties` must be empty (or not iterable). It's hard to diagnose without a complete example, but it sounds like there could be an issue where you're updating the directive's scope and not the parent controller's. A good tool to debug this is [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). When enabled, you can inspect the scope of each element. This may let you see where and when `properties` is set, if at all.

Comment: I will create plunker example. In the meantime, to answer the questions and to give a bit more light to the whole case, initially, properties are empty, but, that is a valid situation from ng-repeat perspective- or not? Could that be the actual problem - the fact that initially I have an empty array?

The parent scope is updated actually. Directive's scope is actually the very same as parent controller scope. This watch I added in directive is actually triggered when data arrives from the server and when it's added to the properties so I would exclude the scope problems.

Comment: I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kHxGd2SUGP03iWs0Lcnt?p=preview). It can be seen in the console that after 3 seconds (timeout) the change on properties is properly picked up by watchCollection within directive, but it is not applied to ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in

```
contentElement.replaceWith(clonedElement.html());
```

Notice here that you're essentially replacing it with raw HTML string code. Hence, Angular has no concept of the directives inside the code. However, I don't see why this is needed at all. Just compiling and attaching the result to scope seems to work just fine:

```
var templateElement = angular.element(angular.element(element.children()[0]).children()[0]);
$compile(templateElement)(scope);
```

Here's the updated, working version:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gxPAP43sx3QxyFzBitd5?p=preview

The documentation for $compile didn't say too much, but $compile returns a function, which you then call with the scope you want to attach the element to (as far as I've understood). Hence, you don't need to store the reference to the element at all, unless you want to use it later.

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't event tried without replacing the HTML. It was somehow natural to replace whit what I've got from `$compile`. And, I've read documentation several times, just to make sure I haven't missed anything, but, I was obviously to sure about the replacing approach.